# install gnu command

Tags: software-installation, osx, gnu, split

I have the command split installed. However I need the '--filter'argument, which is supported by gnu's split command. SO I need to install gnu split. How do I do that on my mac?
I tried

```
$ brew install coreutils
```

but its already up to date. Then I tried doing

```
$ brew install split
$ brew install gnu-split
```

It says the command is not available:

```
Error: No available formula for gnu-split
```

How can I install any specific gnu command, on mac os (and linux as well)?

Answer (score 3):

From https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities

Brew install coreutils

> your commands will be accessible with g préfix so call `gsplit`